# Installing U-SQL Extensions for Local Compiling

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

**I am attempting to use the Python Libraries for U-SQL - Locally**.  I have installed them in the ADLA instance on Azure, I have attempted to download the files locally then register them. I can't seem to get them working. I have looked in the VS 2017 Packages, etc. I can't find them. Has anyone got this working locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a blog post that explains how to install them locally: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2017/02/20/enabling-u-sql-advanced-analytics-for-local-execution/